# Linux - How to compress a set of files and a executable as a unique executable

Tags: linux, executable, deb

Hi all I am running a Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04) and I have just finished and compiled a videogame, and it has generated a bunch of files (they are obviously neccesary) and only an executable, and you have to execute it for opening the game.

Well my question is how could I generate an unique executable with all those files compressed within it, and executing it would be as executing the game executable.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Unless you know how the executable needs to access the data files, you don't.

Comment: download p7zip (the linux version of 7z) this should help a little:  http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/sfx.htm

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What I am trying to do is executing the previous executable I had, which would be located into the just-generated compressed executable file (too many executable words there)

Comment: @Deryck thanks I will look for it there

Comment: The problem is that you also need the data files, and you can't trivially redirect filesystem calls into the archive. And a SFX archive doesn't save anything since the files would be extracted to disk regardless.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yep you are right. I'll research a bit more and tell you if I manage to find anyting interesting. Anyway, thank both you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use `objcopy`.

See here for a better explanation and examples than I can come up with:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967

Comment: I am affraid I don't really get how to use *objcopy* on mi issue. Until I have understood it is used for like translating object files between different architectures, so how shall I create the executable file I am looking for through this command?

Comment: `objcopy` creates an object file that you can link into your executable from the contents of your data file.  You can then access those contents directly from your executable using the symbols `objcopy` inserts into the object file it creates.